# Find the variance of $\underline{x}^{T}A\underline{x}$

Tags: probability, expected-value, quadratic-forms, variance

I was trying to find the variance of a quadratic form $\underline{x}^{T} A \underline{x}$ where it is given that

$$\mathbb E(X_i)=\nu_i, \quad \mbox{Var}(X_i)=\mu_{2}, \quad \mathbb E(X_i-\nu_i)^3= \mu_3$$

and so on. It is also provided that $A$ is symmetric and non-stochastic.

I first centralized the variables by taking $Y_i=X_i-\nu_i$
And after tedious calculations I found the $Var(\underline{y}^{T}A\underline{y})=\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_{ii}^2 \mu_{4}+\mu_{2}^2[(\sum a_{ii})^2-3 \sum a_{ii}^2 +2 \sum \sum a_{ij}^2]-(\sum a_{ii})^2$.
But as I need to find $Var(\underline{x}^{T}A\underline{x})$, I need to calculate some expectations of additional quantities like $E(\underline{x}^{T}A\underline{x})(\underline{x}^{T}A \underline{\nu})$ which I am finding difficult to compute.

Can you offer a way out how to calculate $E(\underline{x}^{T}A\underline{x})(\underline{x}^{T}A \underline{\nu})$ ?

Or , you can give a new approach instead.
Thanks!

Comment: I edited half. Please edit the other half.

Comment: A vector of random variables could be denoted by $\bf X$ (i.e., `\bf X`). The underline is for writing on the blackboard, but this is not a blackboard. Boldface is easy here.

Comment: Are the $X_i$s independent? In that case you can find a derivation in Seber/Lee's *Linear Regression Analysis* provided a common fourth order central moment $\mu_4$ also exists.